# Should I use in-app purchases in this case?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to develop application for some mobile network operators, that allow to set music for **[ringback tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringback_tone)**. In details, I download available melodies list from operator, then when user selects necessary tune I call operator API to set it for RBT. Pretty simple.

But I'm worried about one thing - user should be charged for this service. Off course I'll notify user about it and clearly describe amount of charge. Operator already has billing for this service so I can use it.

As I read in IAP guides, In-app purchases should be used only for digital goods that will be used *inside application* ("Items can only be used in the app where the 
purchase is made"). So here is my question, does it mean that in my case I can use operator billing and I will not have problems with application review?

Comment: In your case I don't think you can use In-app, because the number of ringtones will increase and for each ringtone you will have to create product in itunesconnect. Better you can opt for few free ringtones, and unlock a package that will unlock all the ringtone. By the way you cannot set `Ringtones` in iPhone from downloading the ringtones, it needs to synced with itunes.

Comment: @iphonic, please re-read my question clearly, it's not ringtones, it's ring _back_ tones, signals that you hear when you call to somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after all I've made simple RBT application to check if it will be rejected or not. It successfully passed review.

So, the answer is - no. You shouldn't use IAP in this case.